# react-native-facebook-login: attempt to login results in Instrumentation.java error

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-instrumentation

I am using react-native-facebook-login for users authorization in my react-native app. It used to work just fine, but now it is not working when used with new versions of Android (in particular, with Android Pie). Old versions still work.

When I press Login button, some kind of loading happens, and then Facebook layout with following error shows up: "Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later".

I've checked the logcat, and found this error showed up after the button was pressed.

```
2019-07-25 19:38:53.855 17122-17122/? E/Instrumentation: Uninitialized ActivityThread, likely app-created Instrumentation, disabling AppComponentFactory
    java.lang.Throwable
        at android.app.Instrumentation.getFactory(Instrumentation.java:1233)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1224)
        at X.04T.newActivity(:4122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3587)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2185)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

This stacktrace has led me to Instrumentation.java, so this is the code where error occurs:

```
private AppComponentFactory getFactory(String pkg) {
    if (pkg == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No pkg specified, disabling AppComponentFactory");
        return AppComponentFactory.DEFAULT;
    }
    if (mThread == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Uninitialized ActivityThread, likely app-created Instrumentation,"
                + " disabling AppComponentFactory", new Throwable());
        return AppComponentFactory.DEFAULT;
    }
    LoadedApk apk = mThread.peekPackageInfo(pkg, true);
    // This is in the case of starting up "android".
    if (apk == null) apk = mThread.getSystemContext().mPackageInfo;
    return apk.getAppFactory();
}
```

I am not that good in Java to be able to understand how to fix it, or what is even going on here. I've found some articles where this stuff is mentioned, but all of them are in chinese and not really helping. So, if anyone knows how this could be handled, I'd really appreciate any help.